# Applying for ESTA while living temporarily in another country?

Tags: usa, standard-visitor-visas, esta, german-citizens

I'm a German citizen and am currently doing my bachelors in Norway. When applying for an ESTA tourist visa, which address do I add? My current address in Norway, or the one that is in my registry at my parent's home in Germany? My passport address is therefore not the same as my actual one. I'm also flying from Norway to the US.

Comment: Nitpicky, I know, but there is no such thing as an ESTA tourist visa. ESTA is to _avoid_ having to get a visa.

Answer (score 5):

> When applying for [ESTA], which address do I add?

It doesn't much matter.  I'd probably suggest the address in Norway, especially if you're there for longer than a few months.

> My passport address is therefore not the same as my actual one.

That doesn't much matter either.  Many countries' passports don't disclose the address at all.  If you're asked about the discrepancy, just explain that you're a student and you therefore have two addresses.

> I'm also flying from Norway to the US.

That also doesn't matter, since of course you could be a Japanese citizen residing in Cape Town but flying to the US from Norway.

The important data points are those establishing your identity and that of your passport, and the important questions are the ones concerning your eligibility to travel to the US (the odd ones about your terrorist activities and that sort of thing).

Comment: I believe the ESTA application form asks for the employer, probably also asks for the institution for students, so it’s probably easier/more consistent if the applicant’s address is in the same country.